# Maven - Debug - Can not find symbol

Tags: java, maven, debugging

During using mvn install or mvn compile i got error that maven can not find symbol with different methods and variables in mozilla rhino classes. I made exclusions everywhere where it is possible and said to use 7r5 build for rhino. Also i decompiled jar and got sure that mentioned classes and methods in maven were in that classes. I had pom deps and i couldnt exclude all 3d libraries. So in classpath i saw also path to rhino 6r5 library. I thought that problem was there. So i also decompiled that jar but i saw that methods in the error were also there. My question is how i can debug maven and see what library or class it is using for compiling class. All mozilla rhino libraries which are set in classpath have that methods.
PS: I wanted to mention that mvn eclipse:eclipse works fine and i have no errors in eclipse.

```
[ERROR] ...path_to_class...:[264,65] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getLength()
[ERROR] location: class org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray
[ERROR] ...path_to_class...:[288,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getWrapFactory()
[ERROR] location: variable cx of type org.mozilla.javascript.Context
[ERROR] ...path_to_class...:[322,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getLength()
[ERROR] location: variable array of type org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray
```

Comment: How did you examine the classpath? Did you execute a **mvn:dependency tree** and see if you didn't miss an exclusion of an older version somewhere?

Comment: [INFO] +- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R5:compile only this i found in dep tree. This lib has these classes and methods

Comment: It might be the situation the other way around: that you need to exclude the newer version rather than the older version. I don't know what is on "...path_to_class..." but it may be built against an older version of rhino.

Comment: path_to_class is path to a .java file where error was found. I did it to remove a lot of useless text. I was building without 7R5 and 6r5 exclusions but the result was the same. Otherwase when i exclude any rhino deps errors are starting from import which shows that library not found at all. So i came to a thought that it is using exactly my lib. I decompiled it again from local rep and again that methods were there... Is there any way to debgug maven and check what it is using during runtime? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: hm. it doenst say after exclusion of all rhino libs that rhinos NativeArray class was not found. So it is still found somewhere. How i can check where this class is located?)

Comment: Difficult question to answer, me personally I'd first use a google search on the full classname with package; that usually turns up which jar(s) it is part of. Failing that I would use the search functions of my IDE to try and locate the class in the project. Failing that, I would use a shell script that eats its way through all the jars to try and find it.

Comment: Did you figure it out in the end?

Comment: Yes, i found the problem, thank you. This was cause weblogic jar had it's own rhino implementation. I put my own rhino dep in the head of document and that helped.